# Windows azure blob set properties

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I'm geting an error 'The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

```
 CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.csv");
                            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "text/csv; charset=utf-8";
                            blockBlob.SetProperties();
```

The error is being thrown at SetProperties.

I have seen a few codes where they do not call SetProperties(). Does the contenttype get saved to the blob in such cases?

I did some search and found some people suggesting to check on fiddler.

The following is happening on fiddler..

/xxxevents?restype=container    Result 404

/xxxevents?restype=container    Result 201 Created     ( Container.CreateIfNotExists called)

Now it throws an error while creating the blob.. Request and response headers provided..

```
404 HTTPS   xxx.blob.core.windows.net   /xxxevents/test.csv?comp=properties 215     application/xml waworkerhost:5500



PUT https://xxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxevents/test.csv?comp=properties HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: WA-Storage/4.3.0 (.NET CLR 4.0.30319.18444; Win32NT 6.1.7601.65536)
x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
x-ms-blob-content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
x-ms-client-request-id: 2424933c-1bd7-49fd-998e-11d5499da03b
x-ms-date: Sun, 28 Sep 2014 07:16:04 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey xxx:tQ6DeUSVSq0TIaRjnVQoOgqNJIlHU5k1uay4loMeU04=
Host: xxx.blob.core.windows.net
Content-Length: 0


HTTP/1.1 404 The specified blob does not exist.
Content-Length: 215
Content-Type: application/xml
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: 7845cafa-0001-0033-7d19-af2c68000000
x-ms-version: 2014-02-14
Date: Sun, 28 Sep 2014 07:15:53 GMT
```

Would sincerely appreciate any help

Thanks

Comment: Have you uploaded the blob?

Comment: No, after creating the container I gave the calls mentioned..

Comment: I have successfully uploaded the BLOB using SAS. But now i have a challenge to download the blobs with the file name. Has anybody done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behavior. `SetBlobProperties()` method can only be called on blobs which are there in your blob storage. What you would need to do is upload blob first.

Assuming you're trying to upload `test.csv` file from say `C:\temp` folder, here's what you would need to do:

```
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("test.csv");
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "text/csv; charset=utf-8";
            blockBlob.UploadFromFile(@"C:\temp\test.csv", FileMode.Open);
```

Comment: What does FileMode mean in this context. Also, in which circumstances does one need to call SetProperties()

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why we need `FileMode` in this case as we are always reading from the blob. As I mentioned, you call SetBlobProperties to change properties of an existing blob. To give you an example, let's in the code I mentioned above you forgot to include the 2nd line and uploaded the blob. The blob's content type will be `application/octet-stream`. Now you want to change the content type of the blob. In this scenario, you would use your code to change the blob's content type. HTH.